Which varieties admit Boolean product representation?
In the popular textbook A Course in Universal Algebra it is mentioned the following open problem (p. 289 of the Millennium Edition):
"For which varieties $V$ is every algebra in $V$ a Boolean product of directly indecomposable algebras? of subdirectly irreducible algebras? of simple algebras?"
I would be particularly interested in weak Boolean product of algebras, i.e. sheaves of algebras over a Boolean space.
What are the most recent advancements in answering that question? Can anyone point to some releant recent work? Thanks!

As far as I know, not a lot has been done to tackle this question directly. Vaggione (2000) showed that discriminator varieties are characterized by the property of having all its elements be Boolean products of directly indecomposable algebras together with a special property (Fraser-Horn). Some information on this might also be in A. Knoebel's "Sheaves of Algebras" but I don't know if it might answer this question directly.
